# Convert large dataset into a chunk of random sample

Tags: python, random, chunks

I have a large dataset of 100MB and want to make a chunk of random sample of 500 data. I tried using following but the data is being repeated?

```
di = sorted(random.sample(current,s))
data.append(di)
```

Comment: Does the large dataset of 100MB contain repeats?

Comment: Yes, the data is repeated in dataset.

Comment: And you would like to select 500 values from among the unique values in the data (i.e., no duplicate values in the 500), is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question, you're trying to take a random sample of size 500 from the values in a dataset of 100MB in size containing repeats, and you would like the values in your sample to be unique.

The docs for [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) state:

> If the population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible selection in the sample.

This means that to avoid repeats in the sample of size 500, we need to do something more than simply call `random.sample()`.

One possibility is to create a collection of the unique values in the dataset and take our sample from that:

```py
import random

current = [random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(100_000_000)]
print('number of values in original data is', len(current), sep=' ')
s = 500
di = sorted(random.sample(current,s))
print('number of unique values in the sample of size', s, 'is', len(set(di)), sep=' ')

uniq = list(set(current))
print('number of unique values in original data is', len(uniq), sep=' ')
di = sorted(random.sample(uniq,s))
print('number of unique values in the sample of size', s, 'is', len(set(di)), sep=' ')
```

Output:

```
number of values in original data is 100000000
number of unique values in the sample of size 500 is 395
number of unique values in original data is 1000
number of unique values in the sample of size 500 is 500
```

This shows that if we sample from the original dataset `current` with repeats, there are fewer than 500 unique values in the sample of size 500. However, if we create a collection `uniq` containing only the unique values from the original dataset, we can reliably take a sample of size 500 with all unique values, assuming the number of unique values in the original dataset is at least 500; otherwise, as stated in the docs:

> If the sample size is larger than the population size, a ValueError is raised.